# Can't get number of month for a specific month in the Portuguese version of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I am obtaining the number of months for the Portuguese names of the months using Google Sheets. For most months, the formula below works:

```
=MONTH("01/"&A1&"/01")
```

Except for `Setembro` (in English, September). The error returned is that

> Função MONTH parâmetro 1 espera os valores número, mas
>   "01/Setembro/01" é na verdade texto e não pode ser forçado para
>   número.

Which translated is:

> The parameter 1 of the MONTH function expects numerical values, but
>   "01/Setembro/01" is in fact text and can't be forced to number.

[image]

[Here is a sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-E-8MD56PenmoWfE33OoejGSZFBtogVA5ccBrL8yQR4/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Works perfectly for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctllH.png

Comment: @Kos, weird. Please, could you tell me which OS, browser and system language you are using?

Comment: Note that error message you got refers to different text format: "01-Setembro-01"

Comment: @kos, the same happens with  "01/Setembro/01". I will edit my question

Comment: Here's [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBdILdtSmHWJZoDiVGF5EdYqJkIhmnZ8Bq98hYLzzww/edit#gid=1217666102) I have noticed that sometimes it really gives error on same input, what I did to fix it: delete month name and drag month down to the cell

Comment: Thanks, @kos. I open your sheet and made a copy and it works on my end. I started from scratch in a [new spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-E-8MD56PenmoWfE33OoejGSZFBtogVA5ccBrL8yQR4/edit?usp=sharing) but the error persists, even trying your hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google translate built in function on sheets to convert September to english and use is that way -

`=MONTH("01/"&GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1,"pt","en")&"/01")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I am getting the same error. And now it happens for all months. [Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-E-8MD56PenmoWfE33OoejGSZFBtogVA5ccBrL8yQR4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What locale is your spreadsheet set fOr?

Comment: Brasil. If I change it to the United States, the function works.